# How can I find all duplicate questions of a specific tag?

Tags: support

How can I find all duplicate questions of a specific tag, e.g., all the questions marked as `[duplicate]` for the tag, [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
duplicate:yes [spring-boot]
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes%20%5Bspring-boot%5D), have fun.